# When the window is restored down, the appearance of jstree becomes different

Tags: css, jstree

Good day! I am using jstree and it works just fine. However, when I restore down the window, its appearance becomes different. Here are the screenshots.

[Original window size](http://i60.tinypic.com/35lwavl.jpg) 
[After restoring down](http://i60.tinypic.com/168agjo.jpg)

Please help me make them not to change appearance. I have to place the tree on the left side of the page and they should retain their original form. The css (with the whole code) is available in jstree.com. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like a problem depends on your computer.

Even so, **maybe just maybe** if you have any window animation when minimizing or maximizing your browser window, css media queries on your site or widget catches that window resize event and behave depends on that changes.